# how to draw good safari button icons?

Tags: safari, icon, resolution, safari-extensions

I have created a safari extension with tool button icon of 64x64 pixels. its not as crisp as the safari buttons. I have tried higher resolutions and lower resolutions which are rendered worse than 64x64 size.

In below image notice how my custom tab switch icon on the left differ with the safari's on the right.

[image]

the difference is much clearer on an low res external monitor

[image]

How to make crispier and darker images like that of the default safari buttons?

Comment: I can't help but wonder if it has to do with the alignment of your icon. Kinda like this post from IconFactory: http://blog.iconfactory.com/2015/11/the-new-favicon/

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @jefe2000, it was a problem with alignment.  I was able to create a good icon with 17x17 pixels rather than 16x16 pixels as suggested by Apple in the [Safari Extensions Development Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/AddingButtonstotheMainSafariToolbar/AddingButtonstotheMainSafariToolbar.html).